# Sequentially $()show from within a function

Tags: jquery

I use a function that onclick runs to read an xml catalog and opens a thumbnail for each catalog entry.

I want the script to open each thumb suquentially. And logically I feel it should do that as the show command is at the end of the for loop. But the function runs and all the thumbnails show at the same time. How can I change this? Why does this happen?

```
function showproductthumbnails() {

for (i=0;i<xmlcatalog.length;i++){ 

$(catalogitem+i).show("fold", {size:3}, 300);   

}

}
```

Note that the code above is just the abstract with the meat taken out, but the problem remains.

Comment: It could be that the browser only updates the UI *after* your script finishes. If this is the case, you may need to set a timeout which shows the first thumbnail and sets a timeout which shows the second thumbnail, etc, etc. The timeouts will give the browser a chance to refresh the UI. If you think this should be written as an answer I can give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I change this?

You can add a small [`delay` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/delay):

```
$(catalogitem+i).delay(i*100).show("fold", {size:3}, 300);
```

> Why does this happen?

The loop is amazingly fast and calling `show` like this is not blocking. Animation functions are **asynchronous**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is that [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show) – like all jQuery animation functions – is asynchronous. Calling `show` sends instructions to the queue and then returns immediately.  So you call `show` on all the elements simultaneously.

The way round this is to use the [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) function.  This adds a delay to the effects queue.  You need to delay the animation by `300` multiplied by `i` – the position in the loop.

```
$(catalogitem+i).delay(i * 300).show("fold", {size:3}, 300);
```

This means that the first item will have its animation delayed by `0 * 300` ms (0ms), the second by `1 * 300` ms (300ms), the third by `2 * 300` ms (600ms), etc.

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to bind a custom event to each thumbnail. Have the event run the `show()` animation for the thumbnail to which it is bound, and then, on callback, select and trigger the same-named custom event bound to the `.next()` element. The net effect is a cascade of `show()` animations, each calling the next, until the last thumbnail is reached.

Something like this:

```
$('.thumbnail').bind('showme', function(){ // for each thumbnail, bind 'showme'
  $(this).show([your_options], function(){ // thumbnail shows itself
    $(this) // starting here...
    .nextAll('.thumbnail:first') // ...select the next thumbnail
    .trigger('showme'); // ...and trigger the same, recursion-style
  });
})
.first() // then, at the first thumbnail...
.trigger('showme'); // ...start the dominoes falling
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.show()` merely starts the animation, and then moves on to other things while the animation is running.  In your case, the loop quickly starts all the animations, and they all run together.  There are a couple of options to remedy this:

Use `setTimeout()` to delay the onset of each animation, like so:

```
var animationTime = 300;
for (i=0;i<xmlcatalog.length;i++){ 
    setTimeout( function() { $(catalogitem+i).show("fold", {size:3}, animationTime); }, animationTime*i;
}
```

The first time through, the delay will be 0ms, the second will be 300ms, the third will be 600ms, etc.

If you don't want to worry about calculating the times that each animation should start, you can use the optional `callback` parameter of `$.show()`, which fires once the animation is complete:

```
function showThumb(i) { // recursively calls each item after the current one is done
    if (i>=xmlcatalog.length) 
        return;
    else
        $(catalogitem+i).show(300, function() { showThumb(i+1); });
}
function showproductthumbnails() {
    showThumb(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there are already jQuery based answers, so here's a more rudimentary version using timeouts as per my comment:

http://jsfiddle.net/n6A9B/1/

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var imgSrc = "http://bits.wikimedia.org/skins-1.17/vector/images/search-ltr.png?301-3";
    var thumbnails = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        thumbnails.push(imgSrc);
    }

    function showThumbnails(thumbnails, i) {
        if (i >= thumbnails.length) {
            return;
        }
        $(document.body).append($("<img src=" + thumbnails[i] + "/>"));
        setTimeout(function () {
            showThumbnails(thumbnails, i+1);
        }, 100);
    }

    showThumbnails(thumbnails, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different method that uses the completion function of the `.show()` function to start the next one.

```
function showproductthumbnails() {
    var cntr = 0;
    function showNext() {
        if (cntr < xmlcatalog.length) {
            $(catalogitem+cntr).show(300, "fold", showNext);
            ++cntr;
        }
    }
    showNext();
}
```

This does the first show and sets a completion function that will kick off the next one and it will stop when the cntr gets to the limit.  This guarantees that they follow each other sequentially.